# How to detecting real IP from UCbrowser in Nginx proxy?

Tags: nginx

I have nginx proxy server and application on python. When I got request from UCbrowser I see this headers

```
HTTP_CLIENTIP': '223.176.141.141'
'HTTP_X_REAL_IP': '168.235.197.149'
'REMOTE_ADDR': '168.235.197.149'
'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR': '223.176.141.141, 168.235.197.149'
```

Client ip is 223.176.141.141 but geoip detect wrong counry with ip 168.235.197.149...
In config I have this options

```
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

and

```
  set_real_ip_from 192.168.1.0/24;  
  real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
```

How to solve that problem that real ip detecting normally?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed ngx_http_realip_module on your server with the nginx ?

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html

Comment: Yep.  --with-http_realip_module